# YouTube GData batch query

Tags: ios, youtube-api, gdata-api

I need to make 50 YouTube video queries with different keywords.(Not a query with 50 components combined by OR).

I found that GData query can be batched, however, I can't figure out how to config the params properly for this API:

```
fetchFeedWithBatchFeed:videoFeed forBatchFeedURL:batchURL completionHandler
```

I'm using `fetchFeedWithURL` for a single query.

So let's say I have some keywords like:

Any help on setup this batch query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, I think I'll just switch to v3.
XML sucks.